# Getting Error message after Invoking Web service in case of a HTTP 400 response code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, asp.net-web-api, actionscript, air

Just written a `web service` (WEB-API) that returns a `400` error message on bad request.

Together with the response, the server sends an error message like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Error>
  <Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
  <ModelState>
    <serviceRequest.Id>The Id field is required.</serviceRequest.Id>
  </ModelState>
</Error>
```

And I use the flash `flex` for the UI and use the following `event handlers` to receive the response.

```
httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=400 responseURL=null]
status: 400
[HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=400 responseURL=null]
```

This retrieves the `status code  = 400` but how to receive the accompanying `xml` from the web service ?

Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Good question!  @Andrey Popov's answer is correct; Flash's networking components are rather primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to always return status OK (200). Flash is a bit dumb on this and mixing headers with content always makes troubles. Nevertheless if you've embedded it to HTML it also depends on the browser.

So best here would be to return a simple OK status with your error inside, and to just check the data on your `Event.COMPLETE` handler. If you have error, then it's an error. Just skip the status thing - it will save you time, efforts and sleepless nights :)

Comment: thank you. But is it not a `bad practise` to send `200` even though an error has to be reported? We have to do this because `there is no way in flash air we can get that data ?`

Comment: Well basically on the regular client-server communication it's pretty true that this is the way, but with flash things are somehow crippled. I truly understand you, but.. it's just the way it is :) On most back-end languages, you can select custom client preview of that error, while Adobe decided to just get the status ;)